# Laravel OrderBy Method not working with paginate() method

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, eloquent, sql-order-by

Friends I am working on a Laravel Project. I have came across a problem where I am trying to use an OrderBy() method. The error message I get is

*** BadMethodCallException***

***Method orderBy does not exist.***

Here my controller code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Episode;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;

class EpisodeController extends Controller
{


public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('admincheck');
}

public function index()
{
    $episodes = Episode::paginate(10)->orderBy('episode_no','desc');        
    return view('episode.index',compact('episodes'));
}
```

In the **index()** I have used **paginate function** and then **orderBy** function which I think is the source of error but I don't know why? If I use only **paginate** function I don't get error. And also If I use other functions like **latest function** after **paginate** I also get same kind of error. I don't Know what is wrong with my code so please guys help me. thank you.

Comment: did you try orderBy() 1st and then paginate() method? eg: `...::orderBy()->paginate()`

Comment: Yeah putting orderBy() first worked. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use it as

```
$episodes = Episode::orderBy('episode_no', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
```

Comment: You can accept this answer so it can be helpful to other people. @SuryaNeupane

Answer (score 1):

You might need to put "orderby()" in front of the "paginate()" in terms of no function "orderby" for the paginate object.